# Simple regular expression in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a table with the following values:

```
ID     NAME        ADDRESS
1      Bob         Super stree1 here goes
2      Alice       stree100 here goes
3      Clark       Fast left stree1005
4      Magie       Right stree1580 here goes
```

I need to make a query using `LIKE` and get only the row having `stree1` (in this case only get the one with ID=1) and I use the following query:

```
select * from table t1 WHERE t1.ADDRESS LIKE '%stree1%';
```

But the problem is that I get all rows as each of them contains `stree1` plus some char/number after.

I have found out that I can use `REGEXP_LIKE` as I am using oracle, what would be the proper  regex to use in:

```
select * from table t1 WHERE regexp_like(t1.ADDRESS ,'stree1');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that this would be the reg-ex you are seeking:

```
select * from table t1 WHERE regexp_like(t1.ADDRESS ,'stree1(?:[^[:word:]]|$)');
```

If you want to, you can further simplify this to:

```
select * from table t1 WHERE regexp_like(t1.ADDRESS ,'stree1(?:\W|$)');
```

That is, 'stree1' is not followed by a word character (i.e., is followed by space/punctuation/etc...) or 'stree1' appears at the end of the string. Of course there are many other ways to do the same thing, including word boundaries 'stree1\b', expecting particular characters after the 1 in stree1 (e.g., a white-space with 'stree1\s'), etc...

Comment: That may return the character after stree1 (non-word or EOL). You may need to use stree1(?=\W|$) if it does add unwanted characters or use stree1\b which matches any word boundary.

Comment: In this SQL query, it's not a matter of what the regex would "return", but simply what it would match. If he was actually capturing, then a forward lookahead would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
stree1\b
```

Answer (score 0):

The first '\W' is tells it it a non-word character since you need noting after 'stree1' but space
and '$' tells take it as a valid string if it ends with stree1

```
select *
from table1
where regexp_like(address,'stree1(\W|$)')
```